# Cannot make gwt:compile work for a GWT application

Tags: java, gwt

When running `gwt:compile` my application is throwing this error:

> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:127) [INFO] 
>   [ERROR] Could not find
>   org.jboss.errai.bus.client.framework.RpcProxyLoaderImpl in types
>   compiled from source. Is the source glob too strict? [INFO]    [ERROR]
>   Errors in
>   'org/jboss/errai/bus/client/framework/ClientMessageBusImpl.java'
>   [INFO]       [ERROR] Line 985: Rebind result
>   'org.jboss.errai.bus.client.framework.RpcProxyLoaderImpl' could not be
>   found

I can't seem to find the root cause of this error, what could be causing this? And what is this "Is the source glob too strict?"

Using maven and GWT 2.7.0

Comment: MIght help : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/CytAMXtADZk and http://gwtnews.blogspot.in/2015/03/re-update-gwt-27.html